# Unable to figure out why my implementation of Selection sort as a java method not working as expected

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, data-structures, selection-sort

Unable to figure out why my implementation of Selection sort as a java method not working as expected.

```java
class SelectionSort {
    void SelectionSortMethod(int[] array) {
        int min, temp = 0;
        SwapClass swap = new SwapClass();
        ArrayPrinting AP = new ArrayPrinting();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] < array[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            swap.SwapMethod(array[i], array[min], temp);
        }
        AP.ArrayPrintMethod(array);
    }
}
class SwapClass {
    void SwapMethod(int x, int y, int temp) {
        if(x==y) {
            return;
        }
        temp = x;
        x = y;
        y = temp;
    }
}
public class SelectionSortMainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 22, -1, 34, 45, 21, -44, -33, 123, 9, 3 };
        SelectionSort sort = new SelectionSort();
        sort.SelectionSortMethod(a);
    }
}
class ArrayPrinting {
    void ArrayPrintMethod(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**I am expecting the array to be sorted in acsending order but the out is coming out to be the original array.**
**The actual out put is original array passed in main method. But the expected output is that the array should be sorted in ascending order.**

Comment: Your `SwapMethod` is wrong (since it swaps local variables, it doesn't affect the array). Besides that, there's no reason to have a `SwapClass`.

Comment: @Eran Thank you for helping. But I needed to keep different methods in separated classes and call them using thier class objects. And I debugged the SwapMethod and found out values getting passed from array and getting swapped.

Comment: If you must keep that SwapClass, you can keep it, but you should pass to `SwapMethod` the array and the indices of the elements to be swapped. When you pass the values to be swapped you can't modify the array.

Comment: But I am already passing the array in SortMethod() and calling the SwapMethod() inside SortMethod() in outer for loop and expecting the array elements to be swapped during the traversal (using outer loop) in a similar way a code for bubble sort or selected sort would work when all code is written in main method.

Comment: Java is a pass by value language. Therefore the `swap.SwapMethod(array[i], array[min], temp)` call doesn't change the value of any of the passed arguments. Therefore `array[i]` and `array[min]` remain unchanged.

Comment: I debugged the SwapMethod() and found out values getting passed from array and getting swapped.

Comment: You should debug the values of the array after that method returns, and you'll see that the array remains unchanged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205017/discussion-between-anjani-kumar-and-eran).

Comment: edited the SwapMethod() but still the output is same original method:class SwapClass {

 void SwapMethod(int[] array, int x, int y) {
  if(x==y) {
   return;
  }
  int temp = array[x];
  array[x] = array[y];
  array[y] = temp;

 }
}

Answer (score 0):

In the inner for loop array[min] needs to be compared with array[j] instead of array[i].

In the SwapMethod the array elements are not getting swapped, instead values of variables X and y are getting swapped.